# mod_proxy bad gateway after upgrading from 2.4.34 to 2.4.39

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy

I have the following in my Apache Config, no changes have been done, it will work in Apache 2.4.34 but after upgrading to 2.4.39, it starts to throw Bad Gateway error.

under mod_proxy.c

```
ProxyPass /reports http://domainname:10080/reports/

ProxyPassReverse /reports http://domainname:10080/reports/
```

The proxy config is relatively simple so I am not sure if I am missing any thing or there are some important changes done on mod_proxy.c which requires some update. However from the official site and tutorial, this is as simple as it gets.

Logs (IP information Redacted, rest are the same)

```
[Wed Sep 04 11:36:09.191115 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 2574:tid 47621331556672] proxy_util.c(2887): AH02824: HTTP: connection established (Redacted) 

[Wed Sep 04 11:36:09.191144 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 2574:tid 47621331556672] proxy_util.c(3054): AH00962: HTTP: connection complete to (Redacted) 

[Wed Sep 04 11:36:09.191154 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 2574:tid 47621331556672] [remote (Redacted):10080] AH01964: Connection to child 0 established (server (Redacted):443)

[Wed Sep 04 11:36:15.911147 2019] [ssl:debug] [pid 2574:tid 47621331556672] ssl_engine_io.c(1372): (70014)End of file found: [remote (Redacted):10080] AH02007: SSL handshake interrupted by system [Hint: Stop button pressed in browser?!]

[Wed Sep 04 11:36:15.911200 2019] [ssl:info] [pid 2574:tid 47621331556672] [remote (Redacted):10080] AH01998: Connection closed to child 0 with abortive shutdown (server (Redacted):443)

[Wed Sep 04 11:36:15.911236 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 2574:tid 47621331556672] (70014)End of file found: [client (Redacted):59814] AH01084: pass request body failed to (Redacted):10080 

[Wed Sep 04 11:36:15.911250 2019] [proxy_http:error] [pid 2574:tid 47621331556672] [client (Redacted):59814] AH01097: pass request body failed to (Redacted):10080 ((Redacted)) from (Redacted) ()
```

Thanks

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.39 (Unix)
Server built:   Apr  5 2019 15:50:24
Server's Module Magic Number: 20120211:84
Server loaded:  APR 1.6.2, APR-UTIL 1.6.0
Compiled using: APR 1.6.2, APR-UTIL 1.6.0
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     event
  threaded:     yes (fixed thread count)
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
```

**Updates**
I can confirm that the issue is only because of the module mod_proxy.so as i replaced this particular module from my older apache version and it works normally.

From the change log, https://www.apachelounge.com/Changelog-2.4.html
I saw the following, not sure if this is the issue (Version 2.4.38)

"mod_proxy: If ProxyPassReverse is used for reverse mapping of relative
     redirects, subsequent ProxyPassReverse statements, whether they are
     relative or absolute, may fail.  PR 60408.  [Peter Haworth < pmh1wheel gmail.com>]"

Comment: I have tried various solutions like adding timeout, proxyBadHeader Ignore etc
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/169453/bad-gateway-502-error-with-apache-mod-proxy-and-tomcat